# call function on Pressing Done or return key of uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I want to perform some task on pressing done key of uitextfied 
I had tried on that way

```
 -(void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   [self myfuction];
  }
```

but nothing happend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set `delegate` of `UITextField` ? such like

```
myTextFieldObj.delegate = self;
```

If YES then put break point at body of `myfuction` and check it's worked or not ?

**EDIT**

Delegate method should be

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

**NOT** `-(void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` , Its return `BOOL` not `void` so your code should be..

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   [self myfuction];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: searchBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [searchBarTextField setDelegate:self];

Comment: Thanks I hav solved  i replaced [searchBarTextField setDelegate:self] with your suggestion searchBarTextField.delegate = self; and its work

Comment: @user3262371 - ok.. also you need to change your delegate method void to BOOL return type and also accept my answer if it is helpful for you.